# Favicon Ignore Route in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On my MVC projects I usually have the following routes:

```
RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.([iI][cC][oO]|[gG][iI][fF])(/.*)?" });
```

Do I still need the favicon route and now with other icons, such as appleicons, to I need to add other ignone routes?

What should I do?

Thank You,

Miguel

Comment: What do you mean by 'other icons'?

Comment: I mean these ones: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the browsers do a request each time but only for favicon ...

So there is no need to use Ignore Routes for other type of icons such Apple Icons.